Does FLS Need to be Validated for Attachments?
Running the Salesforce DFA scanner on our code flagged a missing FLS validation:

ApexFlsViolationRule  FLS validation is missing for [INSERT] operation on [Attachment] with field(s) [Body,ContentType,ParentId].

As it says, the insert is on an Attachment, and as far as I know there are no FLS controls on those. Of course I could add code to check that the user can write to those fields, but it seems a bit daft. It means there's more code to maintain and more to execute at run time, all for something that's redundant as far as I'm aware, so I'd rather not do it.
That said, docuemnting the false positive is also effort, and also requires ongoing maintenance.
Yes, I am aware that posting this was potentially more effort than either, but it'd be nice to have an answer.
Essentially, if my assumptions are correct it'd be better if the scanner didn't report this in the first place, but since it does do I need to put these checks in place for the sake of security review?
